# Making facet with gglagplot

Tags: r, grid, forecast

I am using package forecast() and I trying to making facet with gglagplot function.

```
#Code
library(forecast)
library(gridExtra)


# GGLAGPLOT 1
 gg1<-gglagplot(TEST_1,lags = 52)

# GGLAGPLOT 2       
 gg2<-gglagplot(TEST_2,lags = 52)

# GGLAGPLOT 3
 gg3<-gglagplot(TEST_3,lags = 52)
```

And this pic below is example of one of three gglagplot.

[image]

I try with this function below but my facet is not good and look like pic below.

```
 # Trying facet
grid.arrange(gg1,gg2,gg3)
```

So can anybody help me to make facet like facet below ?
[image]

So can anybody help me to make better facet like pic below ?

[image]

Comment: Lay it out with 1 row instead of 1 column, i.e. `nrow = 1` in `grid.arrange`. And probably just view/save it to a larger size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all three plots have the same legend, you can remove the legends from the plots and save it separately using the package *ggpubr*:

```
#Code
library(forecast)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggpubr)

# GGLAGPLOT 1
 gg1<-gglagplot(TEST_1,lags = 52) + theme(legend.position = "none")

# GGLAGPLOT 2       
 gg2<-gglagplot(TEST_2,lags = 52) + theme(legend.position = "none")

# GGLAGPLOT 3
 gg3<-gglagplot(TEST_3,lags = 52)

# SAVE LEGEND
gg3_legend = get_legend(gg3)


# Plot everything together
grid.arrange(gg1,gg2,gg3 + theme(legend.position = "none"), as_ggplot(gg3_legend), nrow = 1)
```

If you don't save the legend separately, the last plot would be smaller than the first two.